# How can i embed the barcode scanner in my application?

Tags: android, android-widget, zxing

How can i embed the the barcode scanner into my application such that when i start the application, the barcode scanner screen is actually a part of another activity.. the barcode scanner screen itself should be one of the screens.. on top i should be able to have a textview controlled from my custom activity and at the bottom the barcode scanner which is from the zxing library... One way i know is using fragments.. but then i want to support all platforms starting 2.2 and that wont be possible in this case.. Please help anyone, if anyone has the answers...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app

Answer (score 0):

To do that, your Activity needs to extend ActivityGroup.  I think my response in this question contains the details:

[Tabs using Fragments on Android, but inside another Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968078/tabs-using-fragments-on-android-but-inside-another-layout/7968181#7968181)

A big problem with this is that Google is planning to deprecate the ActivityGroup class.  I understand why they have created Fragments, and they are important.  But I still think ActivityGroup is needed for cases like yours.